# how to make keyboard not override my buttons

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a login screen

and on some devices ( that are not  too tall) the keyboard overrides some of the buttons

see picture of login screen :

[image]

this is on my nexus 7 device, and the edit texts and buttons are in the middle of the screen, not the top

on my particular device, because it is tall enough, the keyboard never reaches the buttons, so i don't have the problem of keyboard overlaying buttons

but on smaller devices, the keyboard can get as high as the login button

what do i need to do to make sure that my screen floats up so that the login button and forgot password are fully visible with the keyboard on the screen ?

Comment: try looking at: android:windowSoftInputMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has the so-called *Input Method Framework* to support different input methods, e.g. keyboard, soft-keyboard, handwriting etc. If the soft-keyboard is used it is diplayed at the bottom of the screen once the user select an text view to edit it, and it can sometimes overlap elements which at the bottom, but you can use resize method, so elememts will fit in rest of the screen.

To change the mode to “resize” add the following statement to your activity in AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name=".DocEdit"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: @Lena Bru did this help you?